# Word Searcher from Words.list

Tags: python, string, list, wordsearch

I was helping my mom with this word search app earlier while taking a break from some python tutorials and I realized -- what a perfect example of something interesting for me to work on/learn from.

Here's what I came up with, and while it works, I have to do some extra steps to figure out the words.

It seems that my double characters don't register as two, and one of them gets replaced with a non-relevant letter.

I've tried a lot of different things -- popping, removing. for character in words and not in myletters (to subtract out the difference). A lot of what I found involving this stuff were grids, and directionals, but I'm really just interested in a split list of words from my character input. Any help is appreciated.

Sidenote - I am very new to coding, so idk if this was the appropriate route. This x was x * 10 simpler than any example I could find. (Maybe why it doesn't work the way I want it to? ;p)

```
wordlist = open("PossibleWords.txt", "r").read().split()
myletters = input("Letters?: ").lower()
s = list()
sorted = str(myletters)

for word in wordlist:
    if len(word) == len(myletters) and all(letter in word for letter in sorted):
        s.append(word)
for length in s[:100]:
print(length)
```

Comment: It's good to see that your doing something to help out your mom, but could you perhaps ad some example input plus expected output? Its difficult to see what you need help with here, and why your code is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OP's recent comment, it sounds like we're taking about *word search*.  To not lose the double letters, we'll use `Counter` and compare counters:

```
from collections import Counter

def is_sub_count(counter_super, counter_sub):

    counter_sub.subtract(counter_super)

    return all(count <= 0 for count in counter_sub.values())

myLetters = input("Letters?: ").lower()
myCount = Counter(myLetters)
myLength = len(myLetters)

words = open("PossibleWords.txt").read().split()

found = list()

for word in words:
    if len(word) <= myLength and is_sub_count(myCount, Counter(word.lower())):
        found.append(word)

print(*found, sep='\n')
```

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
Letters?: uassage
a
age
ague
as
ass
assuage
gas
gauss
guess
sag
saga
sage
sausage
sea
sue
us
usage
use
>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for keeping my code and adding pretty much what I needed, but my new problem is why I avoided the word "anagrams" in the first place. I'm not trying to just find words that are the same length as my input, but also all words that can be made with any of my input. Such as  if len[word]  < myLetters.

Comment: @user9114527, I've reworked my example accordingly.  Instead of simply comparing counters with `==`, I wrote a function to test if one was a subset of the other.

Comment: You're awesome, that was driving me insane. Thank you so much for your help.